# React native IOS voice over on parent view and child component (accessibility)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wcag

Is it possible to have a voiceOver on a View and its child Component? I try to use a voiceOver on a parent View and its child component and write it like this

```
<View accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={'Parent View!'}>
     <Text accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={'First Text'}>text one</Text>
     <Text accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={'Second Text'}>text two</Text>
</View>
This one only read the voiceOver of view(Parent)

<View accessibilityLabel={'Parent View!'}>
     <Text accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={'First Text'}>text one</Text>
     <Text accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={'Second Text'}>text two</Text>
</View>
This code only read the voice over of the child and skipped the parent View
```

is there any solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that all elements have `accessible={true}` by default. I believe that you setting it to true is causing the problem. Try removing the accessible tags.

> When an element has the property accessible={true}, it’s actually makes the children of that element inaccessible.

I found this article helpful: https://medium.com/@larenelg/creating-inclusive-apps-in-react-native-the-coding-bit-bd3832349009